# Aggregate values with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've searched the forum but can't quite find what I'm looking for. Apologies if this has already been answered.

I have a table with the following example values:

```
FY     Period  Version   Value
2013   3       1         9954
2013   3       2         9954
2013   4       1         11498
2013   4       2         11498
2013   4       3         11498
2014   1       1         448
2014   1       2         448
2014   1       3         0
2014   2       1         3150
2014   2       2         3150
2014   3       1         0
2014   3       2         0
2014   3       3         5059
2014   4       1         11118
2014   4       2         0
2014   4       3         11118
```

I'm looking to sum the values for the highest version number, within each period and each FY, so the expected result for this particular data set would be:

```
(9954 + 11498 + 0 + 3150 + 5059 + 11118) = 40,779
```

I've done something similar previously with the `over partition` approach but i can't get it to work on this data set. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May we see what you've tried?

Comment: 9954 And 11498 are not within same period or FLY, could you explain it a little more precise ?

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to use `row_number()`:

```
select sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fy, period order by version desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```